# Apply Template for the DataGridCell at runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I would like to apply DataTemplate to the wpf DatagridCell at runtime.

Used the below code, at runtime combobox is appeared with no data.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cmbTemplate">
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPicklist" ItemsSource="{Binding Picklist}" SelectedItem="{Binding PicklistSelectedItem}"/>
            </DataTemplate>


 <Style x:Key="MyContentStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">          
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasPicklist}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource cmbTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

In code behind:

```
Dim oDataGridCell As DataGridCell = CType(grd_elements.Columns(0).GetCellContent(grd_elements.Items(1))?.Parent, DataGridCell)
            oDataGridCell.Style = CType(oUcDatagrid.grd_layout_main.FindResource("MyContentStyle"), Style)
```

I would like to show the data in combobox. Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong and how to correct it to make it work.

Comment: Try to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`  with a `CellTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Its an AutoGeneratingColumn="AutoGeneratingColumn" so dynamically generating the columns. In some particular Datagridcells I have to apply the combobox template. {Binding Picklist} has list of values but not shown in datagridcell

Comment: Please read my comment again.

Comment: ´´´´ Dim oGrdTemplate As DataGridTemplateColumn = New DataGridTemplateColumn
 oGrdTemplate.Header = e.Column.Header                        
 oGrdTemplate.CellTemplate = CType(grdTotal.FindResource("colTxtTemplate_" + e.PropertyName), DataTemplate)                    oGrdTemplate.CellEditingTemplate =CType(grdTotal.FindResource("cmbTemplate"), DataTemplate)  
 e.Column = oGrdTemplate, I used this if entire col has picklist, its working fine but I need it for few cells not for entire column. I have very less knowledge on WPF. the code is what u mean??